# Can't fetch data inside JSON what I want and what's the difference between this two?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, coinmarketcap

I've looked at many similar issues but couldn't find it. My purpose is to get the coin name and value. There are 2 endpoints in the Coinmarketcap API. First one that in the comment line gives me the output I want and it works , but I need the second one but not works. Both have the similar JSON structure.

First endpoint's output like this and JSON https://pastebin.com/xSS85Sbd

```
name: 'Bitcoin', price: 43973.31953486187,
name: 'Ethereum', price: 3097.8947589293316
```

Some errors I got on the 2nd and JSON https://pastebin.com/0sDXXwxm

```
coin.data.map is not a function
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

I tried below and more and several console.log varieties with and without map but could not be succcessful.

```
coin.map(a => ({ name: a.name, price: a.quote.USD.price}))
coin.data.map(a => ({ name: a.name, price: a.quote.USD.price}))
```

```
async function getCoin(){
  try {
    //const response = await axios.get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=2', {
    const response = await axios.get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC,ETH', {
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'key',
      },
    });

    const coin = response.data;
    const result = coin.data.map(a => ({ name: a.name } ))

    console.log(result);

    //return coin;

    } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    throw ex;
  }
}
getCoin()
```

I really wonder where I am wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: check if `response.data` is really JSON, or if it is string, if it is string, you need to parse it into JSON and all should be working

Comment: I did, my data is already in JSON format.

Comment: can you write   console.log(typeof coun);  ?

Comment: object appears and the it's same in the other working endpoint. map function works in first one but does not work in the second whereas both of same things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not run because they have different structure.

In 1st JSON `data` is **array** so you can use map

```
{
...
"data":[{"id":1,"...
...
}
```

In the 2nd `data` is **object** so it will throw error `coin.data.map is not a function`

```
{
...
"data":{"BTC"...
...
}
```

**Update**

You can get coin info like this

```
const result = Object.keys(coin.data).map(coinName => {
  const coinInfo = coin.data[coinName][0]
  return {
    name: coinInfo.name,
    price: coinInfo.quote.USD.price
  }
})
console.log('result: ', result)
```

Comment: thanks a lot i got it. i'm so confused. so how can i get a specific data like price directly ?

Comment: I just added code example, you can check it @genzowakabayashi

Comment: it works. regards.